# Should no throw exception with Depth First Traversal

Tags: java, data-structures, graph

In the code below I'm getting an error "No Exception should be thrown when calling dft on a graph with vertices and edges and with a valid starting vertex."

An `EmptyCollectionException` is thrown if the graph is empty

``NoSuchElementException is thrown when the start node does not exist in the graph.

and a `NoEdgeException` is thrown if the start node has no edges.

As far as i can tell I'm doing everything correctly.. `getNumVertices/getNumEdges` gets the number of vertex/edges in the graph. There is an `isEmpty` method, and i tried that but I got the same result.

is there something i'm missing? probably something simple. i seem to over look the simple stuff.

```
public ArrayList<GraphNode> dft(GraphNode start)
        throws EmptyCollectionException, NoSuchElementException,
            NoEdgeExistsException {

    if (getNumVertices() == 0) {

        throw new EmptyCollectionException("The graph is empty!");
    }
    if (!vertices.contains(start)) {

        throw new NoSuchElementException(start);
    }
    if (getNumEdges() == 0) {

        throw new NoEdgeExistsException();
    }
    boolean[] visited = new boolean[vertices.size()];        
    ArrayList<GraphNode> resultsList = new ArrayList<>();

    dftHelp(start, visited, resultsList);  

    return resultsList;


    private void dftHelp(GraphNode n, boolean[] visit,
        ArrayList<GraphNode> results) throws NoSuchElementException, 
            EmptyCollectionException, NoEdgeExistsException {

    int idx = vertices.indexOf(n);

    visit[idx] = true;
    results.add(n);
    LinkedList<GraphNode> resultsList;
    resultsList = this.getEdgesOfVertex(n);
    for (GraphNode node: resultsList) {
        int newIdx = vertices.indexOf(node);
        if (!visit[newIdx]) {
            dftHelp(node, visit, results);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you know what the exception is? Assuming you’ve coded your helper methods correctly no exception should be thrown.

Comment: I included my helper method for review

Comment: Knowing what exception has been thrown would be a great deal of help. It might not necessarily be one you’ve specified.

Comment: Probably a stupid question, but how do i check? I mean, Im running my simulator and i'm not getting any errors there. Everything compiles.. and runs without a problem. A try catch but how do i catch the exception if i dont know what exception to expect?

Comment: catch (Exception e) {} and print the stack trace.

Comment: I figured it out. at the getEdgesOfVertex() call that method throws an exception. i changed it to adjList.get(idx); and it worked.